# clear the labels text value

Tags: javascript

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Script2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Javascript.Script2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ClearValue(Text1, Text2) {
        var txtClear1 = document.getElementById(Text1);
        var txtClear2 = document.getElementById(Text2);
        if (txtClear1 != null || txtClear2 != null)
         {
            txtClear1.outerText = "";
            txtClear1.value = "";
            txtClear1.innerText = "";
            txtClear1.innerHTML = "";
            txtClear1.outerHTML = ""

            txtClear2.value = "";
            txtClear2.innerText = "";
            txtClear2.innerHTML = "";
            txtClear2.outerHTML = ""

            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblError1" runat="server" Text="Label1"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblError2" runat="server" Text="Label2"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            onclick="btnClose_Click"   />  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



namespace Javascript
{
    public partial class Script2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            btnClose.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ClearValue('" + lblError1.ClientID + "','" + lblError2.ClientID + "')");
        }

        protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

here  iam not able  to clear the  text  value  of  Label .

once i clcik the  button.here i am trigerring the function  to clear the labels values.

but the text  is not getting cleared.

any idea  how  to solve the issue.

thanks.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you have Language A (.NET here) dynamically outputting Language B (JavaScript here), the first step at debugging should be to examine the generated code. Then you question becomes either "Why is .NET outputting this instead of that?" or "Why does this JavaScript fail?" — and that is a lot easier to answer (and lets a lot more people answer since it doesn't require knowledge of both languages).

Comment: Pay special attention to generated control ids and names. For example, maybe Page_Load occurs too soon in the page life cycle to safely access ClientID properties. You might try to add the onclick attribute during the PreRender phase instead.

Answer (score 0):

The ID of an ASP.NET control is not the same as the **id** in the DOM. The HTML element's ID is generated by ASP.NET at runtime.

You can specify the DOM **id** by specifying the ClientID attribute:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblError1" ClientID="lblError1" runat="server" Text="Label1"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that labels  are not suitable for this purpose. Labels changed client-side do not keep their values on PostBacks.  use a textbox instead and make it look like a label by setting borderwidth=0

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="lbl_error" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None"   BorderWidth="0" runat="server" Width="99%"></asp:TextBox>
```

then in javascript write this function

```
function resetlabel() {

            document.getElementById("<%=lbl_error.ClientID%>").value = "";
        }
```